# Lua logic operators are different than other languages?

Tags: lua

So I started messing around with Lua's logical operators **and**, **or** and **not**.
As stated [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html) `print (4 and 5)` will return `5` while `print (4 or 5)` will return `4`.
If you then switch around the numbers so it says `print (5 and 4)` it will return `4`.
I understood the explanation that the **and** operator returns the first operand if it's **false** and the second one if it's **true**, but what I'm used to from languages like C++ is that `print (4 and 5)` returns `4`. How do I get the same result I would get in C++ or similar languages?

Comment: Could you show an example of C++ code that prints 4? `print (4 and 5)` is not C++ code. All/most C-like languages would behave exactly like Lua.

Comment: Use bitwise operations? https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#3.4.2

Comment: BTW logical operator in C doesn't guarantee any particular value for True result

Comment: @JacekCz Are you sure? The standard specifies a true result from a logical operator is guaranteed to be `1` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37292097/5851520, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-logical-operators?view=msvc-170). Maybe you're thinking of the inputs to logical operators (and condition statements like `if` and `while`), which treat any non-zero value as  `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `and`/`or` operators return the truthy value as follows:

### `or`

The first truthy value when evaluated from left to right, after following the operator precedence. This is why you get `4` when `print(4 or 5)` was executed.

### `and`

The last truthy value encountered in the chained `and` operations. Therefore, you receive `4` when you do `print(5 and 4)`.

The above rules are why you can chain `and/or` operations to work as ternary operator when doing:

```
condition and expression or expression
-- which in C/C++ would be (condition) ? expression : expression
```

---

If you are confusion the `and` with `&` from C/C++ languages, then you should be instead using the [bitwise operators](https://devdocs.io/lua~5.3/index#3.4.2).

> `&`: bitwise AND
>   `|`: bitwise OR
>   `~`: bitwise exclusive OR
>   `>>`: right shift
>   `<<`: left shift
>   `~`: unary bitwise NOT

---

For lua 5.2:

```
print( bit32.band(4, 5) )
```

will give you `4`.

Answer (score 5):

This C code does print `4`

```
printf("%d\n", 4 & 5);
```

but it is an accident due to the binary representation of `4`.

Indeed, the code below prints `4`, which is neither `5` nor `6`:

```
printf("%d\n", 5 & 6);
```

If you use the logical *and*, then this code prints `1`, not `4` or `5`.

```
printf("%d\n", 4 && 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up what the & operator does in C/C++. It is a *bitwise* and operation, meaning it looks at the binary representation of the digits.

Essentially, the & operator looks at each binary place value in the two numbers, keeping a 1 if both values are 1 or 0 if either of them are zero. In practice:

```
  0 1 0 0    // 4 in binary
& 0 1 0 1   // 5 in binary
------------
  0 1 0 0    // also 4 in binary
```

The and function in Lua is completely different. You said you understood what it does so I won't explain it again, but the & operator in C-like languages does something completely different. It only operates on numbers, and because of the static typing in those languages using the and keyword will only return a Boolean true or false, not any specific value like Lua does.

Hope this helps. On the off chance you want to do something like have a variable be a value based on a simple test, like if it is greater than a specific number, or a default otherwise, you can do something like this (in Lua):

```
local a = 4
local var = (a > 5) and a or 5
```

This let's you, among other things, set the minimum a value can be with out full if/else blocks.