# Why an error when ORing switch case values?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

```
 switch (ch)
    {
    case '~' || 177: 
        tile->tileType = TILE_NONE;
        return true;
    case '@' || 219: //error here: '@'
        tile->tileType = TILE_WALL;
        return true; 
    }
```

The error reads:
"case value '1' already used"

.....what the hell??

I've tried to clean the solution, restarted, used another PC. I'm "this close" to just reinstalling VS. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: C is a fairly simple and literal language. If you read up on what the `||` operator does, then it should shed light on the situation.

Comment: How do you think reinstalling VS would fix an error in your code? Trust the compiler. 
 When it says your code is wrong, it is certainly wrong.

Comment: @abelenky  reinstalling VS is out of bounds, but restarting the PC isn't?  The computer has trained Xolin_ well, lowering expectations about as far as they can go.

Comment: The next question you will ask why is your char never 219...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot have more than one case divided by `||` like you would an if statement. You have the case

```
'~' || 177:
```

Which is a boolean expression that evaluates to true, [which gets evaluated to `1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37291888/8534008) because cases can only be an integral type (`int`, `char` and `enum`), so it must be converted to an `int`. So you are really saying

```
case 1:
```

The same thing happens in your second case statement, which is evaluated to a second `case 1:`, hence the error

Instead do:

```
case '~':
case 117:
   //code
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a logical OR expression use the switch fall-through behavior:

```
switch (ch)
{
   case '~':
   case 117:
      tile->tileType = TILE_NONE;
      return true;
   case '@':
   case 219:
      tile->tileType = TILE_WALL;
      return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`'~' || 177` evaluates to `true`, which is `1`.
So the line `case '~' || 177:` is really `case 1:`

Same with `'@' || 219` in the line `case '@' || 219:`

You cannot have

```
switch (ch)
{
case 1: 
    tile->tileType = TILE_NONE;
    return true;
case 1: //  "case value '1' already used"  (You used it just above!)
    tile->tileType = TILE_WALL;
    return true; 
}
```

---

The error message is perfect and precise.
Why did you think you should reboot your PC or reinstall the IDE tools?

Answer (score 0):

the `||` operator just checks if any o the expressions at the sides is different from 0, and generates a true value of `1` if any of them is different from `0`, so the first case is:

```
switch(...) {
case 1:
```

and the second case is also:

```
case 1:
```

so, the compiler cannot decide which `case` to follow.

Probably what you mean (and want to do) is this other thing:

```
switch (ch)
    {
    case '~': case 177: /* ch is either '~' or 177 */
        tile->tileType = TILE_NONE;
        return true;
    case '@': case 219: /* ch is either '@' or 219 */
        tile->tileType = TILE_WALL;
        return true; 
    }
```

which means that in case `ch` is any of `'~'` or `177`, do the first part, and when it is `'@'` or `219`, then go to the second part of the above code.